# Places to host reference documents?

Tags: discussion

I am referencing a document, the Apollo Mission Simulator Instructor Handbook Volume 1, that I can't find on the internet.  I see no reason why I shouldn't post this and make it generally available.

I'll post it on my own webserver for now, but I know some community members have been reluctant to visit self-hosted sites due to security/privacy concerns.

Is there a place such a document could find a permanent home on the internet?  I have several others that might be of interest to the community if such a place exists.

Comment: It seems like there are a few sites that might be willing to host information like that, but I don't know of any that openly advertise it. You could try, for example, asking the [Planetary Society](http://www.planetary.org/about/) if they would be willing to host.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of contacting organizations, I was thinking more along the lines of imgur for documents or something.  I'll try contacting ALSJ and see if they have any interest.  Great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Oh, if you were looking for something more generic, there is the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/). It's not just for web pages. They keep archives of documents, among many other things.

Comment: They have an upload tool on their homepage. You may have to be logged in to use it.

Comment: Thanks again. Looks like Internet Archive will work fine.

Comment: If you ever do decide to do self-hosting on your own domain, I'd let the good folks at [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) know so they can whitelist you.

Comment: @Machavity Thanks for the tip! I was unaware of that.

Comment: @Machavity Mind if I roll that into the answer as well?

Comment: @called2voyage Sure. I love to plug Charcoal. Some of the unsung heroes of SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer: there is the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/). It's not just for web pages. They keep archives of documents, among many other things.

If you're looking for something specific to space exploration, I'm not sure if there is a site specifically designed for uploading documents, but there may be sites interested in hosting your material. You could try, for example, contacting the [Planetary Society](http://www.planetary.org/about/).

If you do opt to self-host, let the good folks at [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) know so they can whitelist you. (Thanks, @Machavity!)