# Where did all the Apollo era NTRS documents go? Do we need to preserve them?

Tags: discussion, resources

Lately I'm unable to find documents on [NTRS](http://ntrs.nasa.gov) that used to be available. Example:

"F-1 Rocket Engine Operating Instructions" used to be available. It is referenced on [this page on heroicrelics.org](http://heroicrelics.org/info/f-1/f-1-throat-closures.html) with URL: `http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?N=0&Ntk=all&Ntx=mode%20matchall&Ntt=19750070175`. This now gives a "Page not found" error.

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40829/source-for-apollo-11-descent-time-series-data/57866#57866) user *jumpjack* mentions that some links have changed:

> I also found this forum post listing all "Apollo experience reports" available on NTRS site, but beware that all links are broken due to server change; anyware the documents numbers are still valid.
>
> For example, this link is invalid:
>
> https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19760019157_1976019157.pdf
>
> You must convert it to:
>
> https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19760019157/downloads/19760019157.pdf

However, that last link also doesn't work any more. In fact, many links in that post, which is very recent, from 21 January 2022, are broken now.

Some documents can be found elsewhere, e.g. ibiblio.org or archive.org, but that mileage varies a lot.

Anyone have a clue of what's going on? Do we need to start an ibiblio.org or archive.org project?

Comment: This was a fairly recent change (last couple of years anyway) and I find it very annoying.

Comment: I'd like to find all the R-3896 documents. Perhaps I'll ask a question about it. I saw a collection for sale on ebay :(

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah, I saw that too. Still stuck on the F-1 tuning question, eh? ;-). The document that called2voyage found is enormous. I can't even open it - my computer loads only the first 50 pages or so.

Comment: I did manage to get that one, its over 400 pages and took forever to download from the wayback machine. I think the parts list is in R-3896-4 which I can't find anywhere. I did find an R-3896 "intro" which explained the different documents.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/58652/6944

Comment: The last link  https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19760019157/downloads/19760019157.pdf works for me

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 Really? I get a blank page with `{"statusCode":500,"message":"Internal server error"}`

Comment: Is this a new occurrence? perhaps its transitory

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 it's been like this for me since a couple of days. Sometimes with other links I get code 404 on a similarly blank page (instead of a nicely formatted one). This particular case may be temporary, but the fact still is that a lot of documents have been removed entirely. Or at least don't show up with queries and/or direct links.

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 that particular one worked for me as well, but a LOT of documents have been removed recently, even from the Shuttle era. The last one I noticed was the shuttle EVA tools catalog. Fortunately I had already uploaded it to the internet archive in anticipation :)

Comment: @OrganicMarble any recommendations with regard to uploading documents to archive.org? There seems to be a [NASA Apollo documentation project](https://archive.org/details/apollo-docs), but it's unclear if anyone can just dumps stuff there.

Comment: @Ludo I learned that i.a. lets you do that from a question here! https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1046/6944  I've just been uploading to my own "library", it seems that anyone can access it, at least from links I've used as references here. But I am not a sophisticated i.a. user by any means, I often get lost trying to find stuff there.

Answer (score 5):

In many cases they are probably already backed up to archive.org. Your example links are:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20161210045811/http://www.christophermadsen.com/docs/19750070175_1975070175.pdf
- http://web.archive.org/web/20100517082713/https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19760019157_1976019157.pdf

Comment: What query did you use to find that?

Comment: The second one was simple. I just put the URL into archive.org and it came up. The first one was harder. I had to google the document number. I found another site that hosted it, which unfortunately was also down but thankfully was backed up in archive.org.

Comment: Many thanks for finding the F-1 document, I've been looking for ages. I guess my Google fu took a dive.  But still a shame that NTRS doesn't have them anymore, because finding stuff now becomes a lot harder.

Comment: For sure, one of the more frustrating things about historical reference material.

Comment: There is a lesson to be learned here. When you run across an interesting document, go to archive.org and create a link to the document. Websites change. The archive keeps track of that older stuff.